# Шифр двойной перестановки

Tags: python, python-3.x, криптография, шифрование

Как реализовать шифр двойной перестановки как на рисунке?
[image]

Ключи переставляются в алфавитном порядке (столбцы и строки сортировать по алфавиту ненужно). Я написал одиночную перестановку, как сделать двойную?

```
def Cipher(origin_key, origin_text):
    clear_text = ''.join(origin_text.split()).lower()
    k = len(clear_text) // len(origin_key)
    cipher = {}

    # Populate the cipher dictionary
    for index, ch in enumerate(origin_key.lower()):
        if ch in cipher:
            cipher[ch] += clear_text[index * k: index * k + k]
        else:
            cipher[ch] = clear_text[index * k: index * k + k]

    # Reconstruct the cipher text
    cipher_text = ''.join([''.join([cipher[key][index] for key in sorted(cipher.keys())]) for index in range(k)])

    # Break the cipher text into chunks of length k and convert to uppercase
    return ' '.join([cipher_text[index: index + k] for index in range(0, len(cipher_text), k)]).upper()
```

Comment: Искали тут похожие вопросы? Кажется, про шифр регулярно тут спрашивают.

Comment: Двойную перестановку не нашёл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш шифр состоит из двух перестановок - перестановки строк и перестановки столбцов

Вот пример реализации операции шифрования. Судя по примеру, перед шифрованием удаляются пробелы и добавляются символы `о` для выравнивания по длине. При расшировании нет возможности надёжно убрать  выравнивание и расставить пробелы, поэтому расшифрование возвращает не тот текст, который был зашифрован.

```py
class TranspositionCipher:
    def __init__(self, col_num, row_num, cols_key, rows_key):
        """
        col_num - число колонок в матрице, положительное число;
        row_num - число строк в матрице, положительное число;
        cols_key - часть ключа, перестановка колонок - список чисел от 0 до col_num-1;
        rows_key - часть ключа, перестановка строк - список чисел от 0 до row_num-1.
        """
        assert col_num > 0
        assert row_num > 0
        self.col_num = col_num
        self.row_num = row_num

        assert sorted(cols_key) == list(range(col_num))
        assert sorted(rows_key) == list(range(row_num))
        self.cols_key = cols_key
        self.rows_key = rows_key
        
    def encrypt(self, plain_text):
        # удаление пробелов
        # нужно уточнить постановку задачи, какие ещё символы должны быть удалены
        plain_text = list(plain_text.replace(" ",""))
        assert len(plain_text) > 0
        # Заполнение матриц открытым текстом 
        matrix_size = self.row_num * self.col_num
        matrix_num = (len(plain_text) + matrix_size - 1) // matrix_size
        matrixes = [None] * matrix_num
        for i in range(matrix_num):
            text = plain_text[i*matrix_size:(i+1)*matrix_size]
            # дополнение текста "пустым символом" 
            text += ["o"]*(matrix_size - len(text))
            matrixes[i] = [text[j:self.col_num+j] for j in range(0, len(text), self.col_num)]
        print("DEBUG: матрицы с открытым текстом: ", matrixes)
        # Сбор шифртекста - перебираются столбцы в соответствии с ключом cols_key
        # в столбце перебираются строки в соответствии с ключом rows_key
        cipher_text = ""
        for M in matrixes:
            for c in self.cols_key:
                for r in self.rows_key:
                    cipher_text += M[r][c]
        return cipher_text

    def decrypt(self, cipher_text):
        # Заполнение матриц шифр-текстом 
        matrix_size = self.row_num * self.col_num
        assert len(cipher_text) % matrix_size == 0, "Длина шифростроки должна быть кратна числу элементов в матрице"

        matrix_num = len(cipher_text) // matrix_size
        # создаются пустые матрицы
        # Нельзя делать так: [ [ [None]*self.col_num ] * self.row_num]  * matrix_num
        # нужно создавать каждую строку отдельно, иначе все строки будут указывать на один и тот же участок памяти
        matrixes = [ [ [None]*self.col_num for _ in range(self.row_num)]  for _ in range(matrix_num) ]
        pos = 0
        for i in range(matrix_num):
            M = matrixes[i]
            # Колонки заполняются в порядке, заданном ключом
            for c in self.cols_key:
                # Строки в колонках заполняются в порядке, заданном ключом
                for r in self.rows_key:
                    M[r][c] = cipher_text[pos]
                    pos += 1
        plain_text = ""
        # сборка открытого текста: построчно из матриц
        for M in matrixes:
            for row in M:
                plain_text += "".join(row)
        return plain_text
```

Ваш пример:

```py
text = "заголовок должен быть наполнен смыслом"
# перестановка столбцов дурак -> адкру, перестановка строк пуля -> лпуя
cipher = TranspositionCipher(col_num=5, row_num=4, cols_key=[3,0, 4, 2, 1], rows_key=[2, 0, 1, 3])
out = cipher.encrypt(text)
out2 = cipher.decrypt(out)
print("Сообщение: ", text)
print("Шифр:      ", out)
print("Расшифровка: ", out2)
```

Вывод:

```
DEBUG: матрицы с открытым текстом:  [[['з', 'а', 'г', 'о', 'л'], ['о', 'в', 'о', 'к', 'д'], ['о', 'л', 'ж', 'е', 'н'], ['б', 'ы', 'т', 'ь', 'н']], [['а', 'п', 'о', 'л', 'н'], ['е', 'н', 'с', 'м', 'ы'], ['с', 'л', 'о', 'м', 'o'], ['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o']]]
Сообщение:    заголовок должен быть наполнен смыслом
Шифр:         еокьозобнлднжготлавымлмoсаеooныoоосoлпнo
Расшифровка:  заголовокдолженбытьнаполненсмысломoooooo
```